# Map lookup fields

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I am new to CRM and I need your help. I have a button "Clone" that is shown when a record is selected. When I click that button it opens the quick create form.
I am retrieving the data for the selected record via Web api. Now, what I need to do is automatically fill all the fields in quick create form. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXYiW.png)

My question is how to map the lookup field (name)?

Answer (score 0):

Lookup Field has 3 properties, ID,Name and Entity Schema name. In below code
ID of user, Full name (primamry column), and Entity is systemuser (i.e user entity).

```
// Set lookup column
formParameters["preferredsystemuserid"] = "3493e403-fc0c-eb11-a813-002248e258e0"; // ID of the user.
formParameters["preferredsystemuseridname"] = "Admin user"; // Name of the user.
formParameters["preferredsystemuseridtype"] = "systemuser"; // Table name.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openform#example-2-open-a-form-for-new-record